# FadeInOut animation stopped working on firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, animation, fade

There seems to be an awful lot of questions on this, but not being able to find a solution I will add one more :)

I am using the [Animate Responsive Image Grid](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/) plugin. You can see its demo [here](http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedResponsiveImageGrid/index2.html) to check if it works in your version of firefox. I believe that after a firefox update (now on version 34.0.5 - mac), the fadeInOut animation stopped working. All other animations (slide etc.) work fine. Fade still works on opera, chrome and safari. I am including the entire plugin in case someones has a clue what the issue may with firefox:

```
;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

'use strict';

/*
* debouncedresize: special jQuery event that happens once after a window resize
*
* latest version and complete README available on Github:
* https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize/blob/master/jquery.debouncedresize.js
*
* Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
* Licensed under the MIT license.
*/
var $event = $.event,
$special,
resizeTimeout;

$special = $event.special.debouncedresize = {
    setup: function() {
        $( this ).on( "resize", $special.handler );
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $( this ).off( "resize", $special.handler );
    },
    handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
        // Save the context
        var context = this,
            args = arguments,
            dispatch = function() {
                // set correct event type
                event.type = "debouncedresize";
                $event.dispatch.apply( context, args );
            };

        if ( resizeTimeout ) {
            clearTimeout( resizeTimeout );
        }

        execAsap ?
            dispatch() :
            resizeTimeout = setTimeout( dispatch, $special.threshold );
    },
    threshold: 100
};

// http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_317-array-shuffle-function
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var i=this.length,p,t;
    while (i--) {
        p = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
        t = this[i];
        this[i]=this[p];
        this[p]=t;
    }
    return this;
};

// HTML5 PageVisibility API
// http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/
// by Joe Marini (@joemarini)
function getHiddenProp(){
    var prefixes = ['webkit','moz','ms','o'];

    // if 'hidden' is natively supported just return it
    if ('hidden' in document) return 'hidden';

    // otherwise loop over all the known prefixes until we find one
    for (var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++){
        if ((prefixes[i] + 'Hidden') in document) 
            return prefixes[i] + 'Hidden';
    }

    // otherwise it's not supported
    return null;
}
function isHidden() {
    var prop = getHiddenProp();
    if (!prop) return false;

    return document[prop];
}

function isEmpty( obj ) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}

// global
var $window = $( window ),
    Modernizr = window.Modernizr;

$.GridRotator = function( options, element ) {

    this.$el = $( element );
    if( Modernizr.backgroundsize ) {

        var self = this;
        this.$el.addClass( 'ri-grid-loading' );
        this._init( options );

    }

};

// the options
$.GridRotator.defaults = {
    // number of rows
    rows : 4,
    // number of columns 
    columns : 10,
    w1024 : { rows : 3, columns : 8 },
    w768 : {rows : 3,columns : 7 },
    w480 : {rows : 3,columns : 5 },
    w320 : {rows : 2,columns : 4 },
    w240 : {rows : 2,columns : 3 },
    // step: number of items that are replaced at the same time
    // random || [some number]
    // note: for performance issues, the number "can't" be > options.maxStep
    step : 'random',
    // change it as you wish..
    maxStep : 3,
    // prevent user to click the items
    preventClick : true,
    // animation type
    // showHide || fadeInOut || 
    // slideLeft || slideRight || slideTop || slideBottom || 
    // rotateBottom || rotateLeft || rotateRight || rotateTop || 
    // scale ||
    // rotate3d ||
    // rotateLeftScale || rotateRightScale || rotateTopScale || rotateBottomScale || 
    // random
    animType : 'random',
    // animation speed
    animSpeed : 800,
    // animation easings
    animEasingOut : 'linear',
    animEasingIn: 'linear',
    // the item(s) will be replaced every 3 seconds
    // note: for performance issues, the time "can't" be < 300 ms
    interval : 3000,
    // if false the animations will not start
    // use false if onhover is true for example
    slideshow : true,
    // if true the items will switch when hovered
    onhover : false,
    // ids of elements that shouldn't change
    nochange : []
};

$.GridRotator.prototype = {

    _init : function( options ) {

        // options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.GridRotator.defaults, options );
        // cache some elements + variables
        this._config();

    },
    _config : function() {

        var self = this,
            transEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
                'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
                'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition' : 'transitionend'
            };

        // support CSS transitions and 3d transforms
        this.supportTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;
        this.supportTransforms3D = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;

        this.transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ] + '.gridrotator';

        // all animation types for the random option
        this.animTypes = this.supportTransforms3D ? [
            'fadeInOut',
            'slideLeft', 
            'slideRight', 
            'slideTop', 
            'slideBottom', 
            'rotateLeft', 
            'rotateRight', 
            'rotateTop', 
            'rotateBottom', 
            'scale', 
            'rotate3d', 
            'rotateLeftScale', 
            'rotateRightScale', 
            'rotateTopScale', 
            'rotateBottomScale' ] :
            [ 'fadeInOut', 'slideLeft', 'slideRight', 'slideTop', 'slideBottom' ];

        this.animType = this.options.animType;

        if( this.animType !== 'random' && !this.supportTransforms3D && $.inArray( this.animType, this.animTypes ) === -1 && this.animType !== 'showHide' ) {

            // fallback to 'fadeInOut' if user sets a type which is not supported
            this.animType = 'fadeInOut';

        }

        this.animTypesTotal = this.animTypes.length;

        // the <ul> where the items are placed
        this.$list = this.$el.children( 'ul' );
        // remove images and add background-image to anchors
        // preload the images before
        var loaded = 0,
            $imgs = this.$list.find( 'img' ),
            count = $imgs.length;

        $imgs.each( function() {

            var $img = $( this ), src = $img.attr( 'src' );

            $( '<img/>' ).load( function() {

                ++loaded;
                $img.parent().css( 'background-image', 'url(' + src + ')' );

                if( loaded === count ) {

                    $imgs.remove();
                    self.$el.removeClass( 'ri-grid-loading' );
                    // the items
                    self.$items = self.$list.children( 'li' );
                    // make a copy of the items
                    self.$itemsCache = self.$items.clone();
                    // total number of items
                    self.itemsTotal = self.$items.length;
                    // the items that will be out of the grid
                    // actually the item's child (anchor element)
                    self.outItems= [];
                    self._layout( function() {
                        self._initEvents();
                    } );
                    // replace [options.step] items after [options.interval] time
                    // the items that go out are randomly chosen, while the ones that get in
                    // follow a "First In First Out" logic
                    self._start();

                }

            } ).attr( 'src', src )

        } );

    },
    _layout : function( callback ) {

        var self = this;

        // sets the grid dimentions based on the container's width
        this._setGridDim();

        // reset
        this.$list.empty();
        this.$items = this.$itemsCache.clone().appendTo( this.$list );

        var $outItems = this.$items.filter( ':gt(' + ( this.showTotal - 1 ) + ')' ),
            $outAItems = $outItems.children( 'a' );

        this.outItems.length = 0;

        $outAItems.each( function( i ) {
            self.outItems.push( $( this ) );
        } );

        $outItems.remove();

            // container's width
        var containerWidth = ( document.defaultView ) ? parseInt( document.defaultView.getComputedStyle( this.$el.get( 0 ), null ).width ) : this.$el.width(),
            // item's width
            itemWidth = Math.floor( containerWidth / this.columns ),
            // calculate gap
            gapWidth = containerWidth - ( this.columns * Math.floor( itemWidth ) );

        for( var i = 0; i < this.rows; ++i ) {

            for( var j = 0; j < this.columns; ++j ) {

                var idx = this.columns * i + j,
                    $item = this.$items.eq( idx );

                $item.css( {
                    width : j < Math.floor( gapWidth ) ? itemWidth + 1 : itemWidth,
                    height : itemWidth
                } );

                if( $.inArray( idx, this.options.nochange ) !== -1 ) {
                    $item.addClass( 'ri-nochange' ).data( 'nochange', true );
                }

            }

        }

        if( this.options.preventClick ) {

            this.$items.children().css( 'cursor', 'default' ).on( 'click.gridrotator', false );

        }

        if( callback ) {
            callback.call();
        }

    },
    // set the grid rows and columns
    _setGridDim  : function() {

        // container's width
        var c_w = this.$el.width();

        // we will choose the number of rows/columns according to the container's width and the values set in the plugin options 
        switch( true ) {
            case ( c_w < 240 ) : this.rows = this.options.w240.rows; this.columns = this.options.w240.columns; break;
            case ( c_w < 320 ) : this.rows = this.options.w320.rows; this.columns = this.options.w320.columns; break;
            case ( c_w < 480 ) : this.rows = this.options.w480.rows; this.columns = this.options.w480.columns; break;
            case ( c_w < 768 ) : this.rows = this.options.w768.rows; this.columns = this.options.w768.columns; break;
            case ( c_w < 1024 ) : this.rows = this.options.w1024.rows; this.columns = this.options.w1024.columns; break;
            default : this.rows = this.options.rows; this.columns = this.options.columns; break;
        }

        this.showTotal = this.rows * this.columns;

    },
    // init window resize event
    _initEvents : function() {

        var self = this;

        $window.on( 'debouncedresize.gridrotator', function() {
            self._layout();
        } );

        // use the property name to generate the prefixed event name
        var visProp = getHiddenProp();

        // HTML5 PageVisibility API
        // http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/
        // by Joe Marini (@joemarini)
        if (visProp) {

            var evtname = visProp.replace(/[H|h]idden/,'') + 'visibilitychange';
            document.addEventListener(evtname, function() { self._visChange(); } );

        }

        if( !Modernizr.touch && this.options.onhover ) {

            self.$items.on( 'mouseenter.gridrotator', function() {

                var $item = $( this );
                if( !$item.data( 'active' ) && !$item.data( 'hovered' ) && !$item.data( 'nochange' ) ) {
                    $item.data( 'hovered', true );
                    self._replace( $item );
                }

            } ).on( 'mouseleave.gridrotator', function() {

                $( this ).data( 'hovered', false );

            } );

        }

    },
    _visChange : function() {

        isHidden() ? clearTimeout( this.playtimeout ) : this._start();

    },
    // start rotating elements
    _start : function() {

        if( this.showTotal < this.itemsTotal && this.options.slideshow ) {
            this._showNext();
        }

    },
    // get which type of animation
    _getAnimType : function() {

        return this.animType === 'random' ? this.animTypes[ Math.floor( Math.random() * this.animTypesTotal ) ] : this.animType;

    },
    // get css properties for the transition effect
    _getAnimProperties : function( $out ) {

        var startInProp = {}, startOutProp = {}, endInProp = {}, endOutProp = {},
            animType = this._getAnimType(), speed, delay = 0;

        switch( animType ) {

            case 'showHide' :

                speed = 0;
                endOutProp.opacity = 0;
                break;

            case 'fadeInOut' :

                endOutProp.opacity = 0;
                break;

            case 'slideLeft' :

                startInProp.left = $out.width();
                endInProp.left = 0;
                endOutProp.left = -$out.width();
                break;

            case 'slideRight' :

                startInProp.left = -$out.width();
                endInProp.left = 0;
                endOutProp.left = $out.width();
                break;

            case 'slideTop' :

                startInProp.top = $out.height();
                endInProp.top = 0;
                endOutProp.top = -$out.height();
                break;

            case 'slideBottom' :

                startInProp.top = -$out.height();
                endInProp.top = 0;
                endOutProp.top = $out.height();
                break;

            case 'rotateLeft' :

                speed = this.options.animSpeed / 2;
                startInProp.transform = 'rotateY(90deg)';
                endInProp.transform = 'rotateY(0deg)';
                delay = speed;
                endOutProp.transform = 'rotateY(-90deg)';
                break;

            case 'rotateRight' :

                speed = this.options.animSpeed / 2;
                startInProp.transform = 'rotateY(-90deg)';
                endInProp.transform = 'rotateY(0deg)';
                delay = speed;
                endOutProp.transform = 'rotateY(90deg)';
                break;

            case 'rotateTop' :

                speed = this.options.animSpeed / 2;
                startInProp.transform= 'rotateX(90deg)';
                endInProp.transform = 'rotateX(0deg)';
                delay = speed;
                endOutProp.transform = 'rotateX(-90deg)';
                break;

            case 'rotateBottom' :

                speed = this.options.animSpeed / 2;
                startInProp.transform = 'rotateX(-90deg)';
                endInProp.transform = 'rotateX(0deg)';
                delay = speed;
                endOutProp.transform = 'rotateX(90deg)';
                break;

            case 'scale' :

                speed = this.options.animSpeed / 2;
                startInProp.transform = 'scale(0)';
                startOutProp.transform = 'scale(1)';
                endInProp.transform = 'scale(1)';
                delay = speed;
                endOutProp.transform = 'scale(0)';
                break;

            case 'rotateLeftScale' :

                startOutProp.transform = 'scale(1)';
                speed = this.options.animSpeed / 2; 
                startInProp.transform = 'scale(0.3) rotateY(90deg)';
                endInProp.transform = 'scale(1) rotateY(0deg)';
                delay = speed;
                endOutProp.transform = 'scale(0.3) rotateY(-90deg)';
                break;

            case 'rotateRightScale' :

                startOutProp.transform = 'scale(1)';
                speed = this.options.animSpeed / 2;
                startInProp.transform = 'scale(0.3) rotateY(-90deg)';
                endInProp.transform = 'scale(1) rotateY(0deg)';
                delay = speed;
                endOutProp.transform = 'scale(0.3) rotateY(90deg)';
                break;

            case 'rotateTopScale' :

                startOutProp.transform = 'scale(1)';
                speed = this.options.animSpeed / 2;
                startInProp.transform = 'scale(0.3) rotateX(90deg)';
                endInProp.transform = 'scale(1) rotateX(0deg)';
                delay = speed;
                endOutProp.transform = 'scale(0.3) rotateX(-90deg)';
                break;

            case 'rotateBottomScale' :

                startOutProp.transform = 'scale(1)';
                speed = this.options.animSpeed / 2;
                startInProp.transform = 'scale(0.3) rotateX(-90deg)';
                endInProp.transform = 'scale(1) rotateX(0deg)';
                delay = speed;
                endOutProp.transform = 'scale(0.3) rotateX(90deg)';
                break;

            case 'rotate3d' :

                speed = this.options.animSpeed / 2;
                startInProp.transform = 'rotate3d( 1, 1, 0, 90deg )';
                endInProp.transform = 'rotate3d( 1, 1, 0, 0deg )';
                delay = speed;
                endOutProp.transform = 'rotate3d( 1, 1, 0, -90deg )';
                break;

        }

        return {
            startInProp : startInProp,
            startOutProp : startOutProp,
            endInProp : endInProp,
            endOutProp : endOutProp,                
            delay : delay,
            animSpeed : speed !== undefined ? speed : this.options.animSpeed
        };

    },
    // show next [option.step] elements
    _showNext : function( time ) {

        var self = this;

        clearTimeout( this.playtimeout );

        this.playtimeout = setTimeout( function() {

            var step = self.options.step, max= self.options.maxStep, min = 1;

            if( max > self.showTotal ) {
                max = self.showTotal;
            }

                // number of items to swith at this point of time
            var nmbOut  = step === 'random' ? Math.floor( Math.random() * max + min ) : Math.min( Math.abs( step ) , max ) ,
                // array with random indexes. These will be the indexes of the items we will replace
                randArr = self._getRandom( nmbOut, self.showTotal );

            for( var i = 0; i < nmbOut; ++i ) {

                // element to go out
                var $out = self.$items.eq( randArr[ i ] );

                // if element is active, which means it is currently animating,
                // then we need to get different positions.. 
                if( $out.data( 'active' ) || $out.data( 'nochange' ) ) {

                    // one of the items is active, call again..
                    self._showNext( 1 );
                    return false;

                }

                self._replace( $out );

            }

            // again and again..
            self._showNext();

        }, time || Math.max( Math.abs( this.options.interval ) , 300 ) );

    },
    _replace : function( $out ) {

        $out.data( 'active', true );

        var self = this,
            $outA = $out.children( 'a:last' ),
            newElProp = {
                width : $outA.width(),
                height : $outA.height()
            };

        // element stays active
        $out.data( 'active', true );

        // get the element (anchor) that will go in (first one inserted in this.outItems)
        var $inA = this.outItems.shift();

        // save element that went out
        this.outItems.push( $outA.clone().css( 'transition', 'none' ) );

        // prepend in element
        $inA.css( newElProp ).prependTo( $out );

        var animProp = this._getAnimProperties( $outA );

        $inA.css( animProp.startInProp );
        $outA.css( animProp.startOutProp );

        this._setTransition( $inA, 'all', animProp.animSpeed, animProp.delay, this.options.animEasingIn );
        this._setTransition( $outA, 'all', animProp.animSpeed, 0, this.options.animEasingOut );

        this._applyTransition( $inA, animProp.endInProp, animProp.animSpeed, function() {

            var $el = $( this ),
                t = animProp.animSpeed === self.options.animSpeed && isEmpty( animProp.endInProp ) ? animProp.animSpeed : 0;

            setTimeout( function() {

                if( self.supportTransitions ) {
                    $el.off( self.transEndEventName );
                }

                $el.next().remove();
                $el.parent().data( 'active', false );

            }, t );

        }, animProp.animSpeed === 0 || isEmpty( animProp.endInProp ) );
        this._applyTransition( $outA, animProp.endOutProp, animProp.animSpeed );

    },
    _getRandom : function( cnt, limit ) {

        var randArray = [];

        for( var i = 0; i < limit; ++i ) {
            randArray.push( i )
        }

        return randArray.shuffle().slice( 0, cnt );

    },
    _setTransition : function( el, prop, speed, delay, easing ) {

        setTimeout( function() {
            el.css( 'transition', prop + ' ' + speed + 'ms ' + delay + 'ms ' + easing );
        }, 25 );

    },
    _applyTransition : function( el, styleCSS, speed, fncomplete, force ) {

        var self = this;
        setTimeout( function() {
            $.fn.applyStyle = self.supportTransitions ? $.fn.css : $.fn.animate;

            if( fncomplete && self.supportTransitions ) {

                el.on( self.transEndEventName, fncomplete );

                if( force ) {
                    fncomplete.call( el );                  
                }

            }

            fncomplete = fncomplete || function() { return false; };

            el.stop().applyStyle( styleCSS, $.extend( true, [], { duration : speed + 'ms', complete : fncomplete } ) );
        }, 25 );

    }

};

var logError = function( message ) {

    if ( window.console ) {

        window.console.error( message );

    }

};

$.fn.gridrotator = function( options ) {

    var instance = $.data( this, 'gridrotator' );

    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        this.each(function() {

            if ( !instance ) {

                logError( "cannot call methods on gridrotator prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;

            }

            if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {

                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for gridrotator instance" );
                return;

            }

            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );

        });

    } 
    else {

        this.each(function() {

            if ( instance ) {

                instance._init();

            }
            else {

                instance = $.data( this, 'gridrotator', new $.GridRotator( options, this ) );

            }

        });

    }

    return instance;

};

} )( jQuery, window );
```

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl Hmmm that is super weird then. Why on earth could it not work in the same browser version on different machines?? I checked again and the demo page I reference above, does NOT animate in firefox while it does on Safari.

Comment: Oops sorry, it does not work in FF!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was solved after the new update of firefox...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that jumps out at me is the use of `document.addEventListener(...)` in `_initEvents()`.

The statement is ripe for conversion to jQuery, with the benefit of jQuery's cross-browser fixes.

I can't see why it should fix your issue but you might try :

```
$(document).on(evtname, function() { self._visChange(); });
```

Comment: If you Google something like 'fadeInOut firefox' you'll discover you're not the first to have difficulties. One approach would be to  remove 'fadeInOut' from the plugin's array of allowable effects, and make 'showHide' the default. With a little thought, you could do so only in FF.

Comment: @Roamer-1988 I know I am not the first. I actually mention it in the very first sentence of this post. However, I still want to try understand what's going on or find a way round it. Cheers

Comment: @user2135738, I understand your frustration. We've all been there. Truth is, I don't really know why FF should misbehave like this. I can only think it's to do with the way FF drives the computer's graphics card. If so, all you can do is wait for some future release of FF or hope to find a some fix on the web. I'd like to be of more help but that's my best shot. Good luck.

Comment: You can always poet a problem report to the plugin's site or github or wherever.

Comment: @Roamer-1988, sorry if that sounded frustrated, it wasn't meant to. Thanks for your help anyway.